# How to know a socket is blocking mode or not? On Windows

Tags: sockets, winsock, blocking, nonblocking, mode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In Win32, is there a way to test if a socket is non-blocking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489562/in-win32-is-there-a-way-to-test-if-a-socket-is-non-blocking)

On Unix, I can use fcntl().

Are there any Winsock API I can use to check a socket is blocking mode or not?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4230850/check-is-socket-is-blocking-winsock-specific
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489562/in-win32-is-there-a-way-to-test-if-a-socket-is-non-blocking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Winsock unfortunately (and surprisingly) isn't able to do this.

Comment: May I use the lower level functions to do this?